# Calculate duration of time ranges without overlap in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Postgres 13 and have a table like this

```
| key | from             | to 
-------------------------------------------
| A   | 2022-11-27T08:00 | 2022-11-27T09:00
| B   | 2022-11-27T09:00 | 2022-11-27T10:00
| C   | 2022-11-27T08:30 | 2022-11-27T10:30
```

I want to calculate the duration of each record, but without overlaps. So the desired result would be

```
| key | from             | to               | duration
----------------------------------------------------------
| A   | 2022-11-27T08:00 | 2022-11-27T09:00 | '1 hour'
| B   | 2022-11-27T09:00 | 2022-11-27T09:45 | '45 minutes' 
| C   | 2022-11-27T08:30 | 2022-11-27T10:00 | '15 minutes'
```

I *guess*, I need a subquery and subtract the overlap somehow, but how would I factor in multiple overlaps? In the example above `C` overlaps `A` and `B`, so I must subtract 30 minutes from `A` and then 45 minute from `B`... But I'm stuck here:

```
SELECT key, (("to" - "from")::interval - s.overlap) as duration
FROM time_entries, (
  SELECT (???) as overlap
) s
```

Comment: How do you want to deal with `A` overlapping `C` ?  This should result in a duration of 30 minutes for `A`....

Comment: I would order by `from, key`. In case of A there would be no overlap before it's `from` value

Comment: It is unclear (typo?) why the record for `B` end with `2022-11-27T09:45`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select 
   key,
   fromDT,
   toDT,
   (toDT-fromDT)::interval -
   COALESCE((SELECT SUM(LEAST(te2.toDT,te1.toDT)-GREATEST(te2.fromDT,te1.fromDT))::interval  
    FROM time_entries te2 
    WHERE (te2.fromDT<te1.toDT or te2.toDT>te1.fromDT)
      AND te2.key<te1.key),'0 minutes')  as duration
from time_entries te1;
```

output:

| key | fromdt | todt | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-11-27 08:00:00 | 2022-11-27 09:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| B | 2022-11-27 09:00:00 | 2022-11-27 10:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| C | 2022-11-27 08:30:00 | 2022-11-27 10:30:00 | 00:30:00 |

- I renamed the columns `from` and `to` to `fromDT` and `toDT` to avoid using reserved words.
- a, step by step, explanation is in the [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/cR7kHkC4)

Comment: thank you so much, I guess that solves it! And thanks for the hint about the reserved keywords, didn't have that in mind. I guess it will save me from some problems in the future

Comment: `(toDT-fromDT)::interval` can be simplified to `(toDT-fromDT)`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
WITH DATA AS
    (SELECT KEY,
            FROMDT,
            TODT,
            MIN(FROMDT) OVER(PARTITION BY FROMDT::DATE
                                                                                ORDER BY KEY) AS START_DATE,
            MAX(TODT) OVER(PARTITION BY FROMDT::DATE
                                                                        ORDER BY KEY) AS END_DATE
        FROM TIME_ENTRIES
        ORDER BY KEY) ,STAGING_DATA AS
    (SELECT KEY,
            FROMDT,
            TODT,
            COALESCE(LAG(START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY FROMDT::DATE
                                                                                                                                        ORDER BY KEY),FROMDT) AS T1_DATE,
            COALESCE(LAG(END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY FROMDT::DATE
                                                                                                                                ORDER BY KEY),TODT) AS T2_DATE
        FROM DATA)
SELECT KEY,
    FROMDT,
    TODT,
    CASE
                    WHEN FROMDT = T1_DATE
                                        AND TODT = T2_DATE THEN (TODT - FROMDT) ::Interval
                    WHEN T2_DATE < TODT THEN (TODT - T2_DATE)::Interval
                    ELSE (T2_DATE - TODT)::interval
    END
FROM STAGING_DATA;
```